# Getting a specific value from an XML file using XPath

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

So I have an XML file here, and I want to get a value from it using XPath. The file in question is an XML file in a zip that you can download [here](http://oasis.caiso.com/mrtu-oasis/SingleZip?queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&startdate=20110418&enddate=20110418&market_run_id=RTM&node=DLAP_PGAE-APND&opr_hr=1):

I believe that it's valid XML.

My current goal is to parse out the *last* (newest) `LMP_PRC` value in the document.

My current code looks like this and returns an empty string every time:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr =
  xpath.compile("//m:OASISReport/m:MessagePayload/m:RTO/m:REPORT_ITEM[3]/m:REPORT_DATA[/m:DATA_ITEM='LMP_PRC'][last()]/m:VALUE/text()") ;
String result = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

The `m:REPORT_ITEM[3]` has been an area of confusion for me so I've tried it with just about every number and have had no luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The m:REPORT_ITEM[3] just means the 3rd one that matches.  You're not getting any matches because of:

```
m:REPORT_DATA[/m:DATA_ITEM='LMP_PRC'][last()]
```

You want the relative path from there, not the absolute path:

```
m:REPORT_DATA[m:DATA_ITEM='LMP_PRC'][last()]
```

So the whole thing would look like:

```
//m:OASISReport/m:MessagePayload/m:RTO/m:REPORT_ITEM[3]/m:REPORT_DATA[m:DATA_ITEM='LMP_PRC'][last()]/m:VALUE/text()
```

The other thing to deal with is the namespace resolution.  For a good summary of what is happening in your case, see http://blog.davber.com/2006/09/17/xpath-with-namespaces-in-java/.  So you should add something like:

```
private static NamespaceContext getNamespaceContext() {
    NamespaceContext namespaceContext = new NamespaceContext() {
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            String uri = null;
            if (prefix == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No prefix provided!");
            } else if(prefix.equals("m")) {
                uri = "http://oasis.caiso.com/mrtu-oasis/xsd/OASISReport.xsd";
            }
            return uri;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };

    return namespaceContext;
}
```

And then use that method to set the namespace context on your `xpath` object:

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(getNamespaceContext());
```

Comment: With the code above followed by a System.out.println() I'm not getting anything from the code you posted.

        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//m:OASISReport/m:MessagePayload/m:RTO/m:REPORT_ITEM[3]/m:REPORT_DATA[m:DATA_ITEM='LMP_PRC'][last()]/m:VALUE/text()") ;
        String result = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println("Last value: " + result ) ;

Comment: Edited answer to include namespace resolution.  If you want it to be more sophisticated than what I put up there, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/x-nmspccontext/index.html